# Submit multiple rows jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Im trying to do something similar to this answer: [How to add multiple rows to a jQuery DataTable from a html string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378245/how-to-add-multiple-rows-to-a-jquery-datatable-from-a-html-string)

The only difference is:
I need to add multiple values that i will get from a text area. The first part works perfectly.

```
function Gen(){
var data = require('../../cases/config.json');
var tableHeaders;
var cantidad = 0;

$.each(data.Ge[0].Data, function(i, val){
    cantidad += 1
    tableHeaders += "<th>" + val + "</th>";
});
// Header 
$("#tabGen").empty();
$("#tabGen").append('<thead><tr>' + tableHeaders + '</tr></thead>');

var t = $('#tabGen').DataTable({
    "scrollY": 200,
    "scrollX": true,
    rowReorder: true,
    autoFill: true,
    select:true,
    stateSave: true
});
```

This second part when doing the **t.row.add($(info)).draw();** it doesn't appear all the data that i need to show. So when I check out the other answer I saw that I can add a single row from an html string. So I don't know how can I add multiple values inside of the table.

```
 $('#excel').on( 'click', function () {
    var inf = $('textarea[name=excel_data]').val();
    var rows = inf.split("\n");

    for(var y = 0; y < rows.length; y++) {
    var cells = rows[y].split("\t");

        for(var x in cells) {
            var info = '<td><input type="text" id="inputTextAg'+x+'" name="inputTextAg'+x+'" value="'+cells[x]+'" draggable="true" "></td>'
            t.rows.add($(info)).draw();
        }
    }
 });
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#excel').on( 'click', function () {
    var inf = $('textarea[name=excel_data]').val();
    var rows = inf.split("\n");

    for(var y = 0; y < rows.length; y++) {
        var cells = rows[y].split("\t");

        var info = '<tr>';
        for(var x in cells) {
            info += '<td><input type="text" id="inputTextAg'+x+'" name="inputTextAg'+x+'" value="'+cells[x]+'" draggable="true" "></td>';
        }
        info += '</tr>';
        t.rows.add($(info)).draw();
    }
  });
}
```